# MATLAB determining elementary matrices for LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I am confused by this question I am studying for MATLAB practice.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: Can matlab find the individual elementary matricies to solve or do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: I did it by hand, but it didn't seem like a very quick way of doing it

Comment: I presume you are meant to do it by hand for learning purposes?

Comment: This is a matlab assignment, I am assuming we use matlab. We haven't done this stuff by hand for months.

Comment: I mean use Matlab to do the computation (multiplying the matrices), you figure out the entries...

Comment: I thought that maybe one could make use of the fact that $A=LU$, $E_3E_2E_1A=U$ so, $E=L^{-1}$ where, $E=E_3E_2E_1$ but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this an interesting excercise so, I fired up Octave (poor man's Matlab) and gave it a try. Like I said in my comment, I tried to use Matlab to calculate the elementary matrices using the fact that $E = E_3E_2E_1 = L^{-1}$ but was uncessful. So then I thought that I'd just do row operations and construct the $E_i$ directly. Here is a transcript...

octave:1> A= [1, -2, 3; 2, -6, 5; -1, -4, 0]

A =

$
\begin{matrix}
   1 & -2  & 3 \\
   2 & -6  & 5 \\
  -1 & -4  & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$

octave:2> E1 = [1, 0, 0; -2, 1, 0; 1, 0, 1]

E1 =

$\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 &  0 \\
  -2 &  1 &  0\\
   1 &  0  & 1\\
\end{matrix}$

octave:3> E1*A

ans =

$\begin{matrix}
   1 & -2 &  3\\
   0 & -2 & -1\\
   0 & -6 &  3\\
\end{matrix}$

octave:4> E2 = [1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, -3, 1]

E2 =

$\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 &  0 \\
   0 &  1 &  0 \\
   0 & -3 &  1 \\
\end{matrix}$

octave:5> E2* (E1*A)

ans =

$\begin{matrix}
   1 & -2 &  3 \\
   0 & -2 & -1 \\
   0 &  0 &  6
\end{matrix}$

octave:6>